# Populate the Header Text field of a Material Document under the BADI LE_SHP_GOODSMOVEMENT?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

So I'm trying to populate the header text field of a Material Document. This Material Document is under the Purchase Order.

Currently, I'm trying to use the BAdI `LE_SHP_GOODSMOVEMENT` under the method `IF_EX_LE_SHP_GOODSMOVEMENT~CHANGE_INPUT_HEADER_AND_ITEMS`. Upon debugging, the outbound delivery was selected instead of the material document. Can I modify the field `mkpf-bktxt` of the material document under the BAdI I have mentioned earlier?

I want to populate the field `MKPF-BKTXT` of a Material Document. I want to use the BAdI `LE_SHP_GOODSMOVEMENT` to code it.